# adding new command to linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I have searched the web for long time without success. How can I add a new command to the kernel command line? e.g. a command like `ver` without any arguments, that simply prints `Hello World` message when executed.

Comment: Why does this need to be in the kernel? Sounds like a simple shell script (or C program) to me.

Comment: Just as a try to begin "hacking" the kernel

Comment: I downvoted your question (but gave an answer) because you obviously did not search long enough. And spending hours in reading a *book* on Linux programming, or on Operating Systems, would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) does not handle any commands (but the [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) bootloader can pass some arguments to the booted kernel). It is just handling [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). You could add some new one, but learn about [advanced linux programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) *before* hacking the kernel.

Perhaps you want to add a new command available to your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29). This is quite simple, put a new executable file (either an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable, e.g. compiled from C code, or some [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)) in a directory known to your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). You might also make a new [shell function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell-functions.htm).

The system call to create a new process is [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (sometimes emulated thru some appropriate call to [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)...). [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is difficult to understand, so take several hours to read about it. Almost every process (with a few exceptions, notably `/sbin/init`) is created by `fork`. The system call to execute a new program is [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Your shell will often use `fork` & `execve` to run commands (except builtin ones, like [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_%28command%29)). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what syscalls are done (by some program).

<sup>PS. Don't *dare* hacking your kernel before understanding quite well user-land Linux system programming....</sup>

Comment: I don't have time to explain more, it would take hours and pages. Please read all the links I gave you.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time